# Intelligent bees build a military dirigible -- how is it different?

Tags: airships, aircraft

For this world honeybees have practical philosophies like those of humans. Their architecture is, overall, near identical to the nest design of real honeybees, and they have the same way of life

They have designed a military dirigible. This vehicle is relatively fast for its scale, and relies on archers to bee it. My question is to ask how this airship would differ from one made by humans: Specifically, what differences there would be based on humans' and bees' different scales, forms, and natural design tendencies

Comment: "relies on archers to bee it." I presume "bee" is a verb the same way you "man" a vessel. But what does this sentence mean?

Comment: @Daron The airship relies on archers with bows as its weapons

Comment: ¿Que? bees inventing armed zeppelins ? that would be quite different.

Comment: "Bee it"??  How about "crew it"?  Much less confusing!

Comment: Are the bees themselves the archers? That would require a completely different biology to pull it off. And how should we even imagine it? Every bee has a single tiny bow? Or multiple bees clump together to draw a larger bow? And what are these archers used against anyway? Other bees? Much larger animals? Humans?

Comment: Why do your bees want/need a military in your setting?

Comment: Have they considered making unbeed drones?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### If you are going for beelievability, this part needs some work:

> ...and relies on archers to bee it...

Archery works very poorly at scales much smaller than humans.  A bow accelerates a projectile over the distance of its draw using the elasticity of the bow arm meaning that all other factors being identical, a bee with a bow would be far less effective than a human with a bow.  A good bow made out of natural materials (like wood, resin, horn, and sinew) can accelerate an arrow to about 200 fps (60m/s) given ~30in (75cm) of draw length over which to accelerate the arrow.  However, if you scale that bow down to something the size of a bee, the bow will still have the same rate of acceleration, but only have maybe 0.2in (0.5cm) of draw length; so, instead of firing an arrow at lethal speeds, you would instead fire it at about 1.3fps (0.4m/s).  This is about 1/3 of an average person's walking speed meaning that Bee bows are a no go.

The square-cube law leads to better armor.  When you scale a thing down, the efficacy of armor decreases by a factor of 2, but its mass decreases by a factor of 3.  By this I do not mean that a human, perfectly scaled down to bee size would have X²:X³ better skin, but that the amount of mass you can invest in armor compared to carry capacity scales at X²:X³.  So, if a 100kg animal has 10 kg of natural armor 2.5mm thick, and if you scale that down to a 1kg animal, with 0.1kg of armor, it will be 0.5mm thick, not 0.025mm.  There is obvious a tipping point where armor thickness eventually becomes the bigger factor than armor weight, but if your bees can make bows, they can make armor too, and that armor will be way thicker in proportion than human armor is, but thier bows will not get a longer draw length.

So, even if you could get a bee arrow moving at 200 fps, it would still not be very dangerous because the bee's exoskeleton and armor could be dozens or even 100s times tougher compared to the mass and cross-section of the arrow, than human skin and armor.

#### If they fight using melee:

If you nix the archery in favor of melee bees, then the airship would serve more or less the same role as a modern air-craft carrier: to act as a mobile base extending your operational range.  Bees can fly for about 6 miles between needed food and rest, but airships can float over very long distances barely consuming any energy.  They could also be used to carry your rations, weapons, armor, and anything else you bring to war; so, while the air ships themselves might not do any fighting, being able to float up to an enemy colony instead of flying to it could make a big difference in how well rested your bees are going into the fight.

#### If they use ballistas:

For the reasons mentioned before, you will not be able to make a bee sized bow for killing bees... that said, use a torsion spring ballista made from modern materials, and you could probably make a something about the size of the palm of your hand that could fire a missle fast and heavy enough to harm a bee... only problem here is that it would take many bees to operate it, it would still fire so slowly that bees could pretty much just dodge it, and it would take so long for bees to reload it that you'd only really get 1 shot in before the opposing bees just fly over and melee you anyway; so, it would be grossly impractical as an anti-bee weapon.

That said, maybe it's not anti-bee at all but anti-airship.  It only takes 1 hit from one of these guys to drop an enemy airship; so, maybe each airship would have one to force other airships not to get too close.  So, there may be some tactical uses for a larger ballista, but by in large the fighting would still be a bee-on-bee melee.

#### If they use biochemical cannons:

If you want ranged "anti-personnel" weapons, biochemical weapons like that used by bombardier beetles is probably the best you can do.  The shot itself does not have enough kinetic energy to harm other insects, but the boiling benzoquinone they shoot out is both hot and caustic enough to do considerable harm.  That said, if your bees are at the technological stage of archery, then I would not suppose they have the knowledge of chemistry to a manufacture thier own, similar artificial weapon system... that said, they have airships; so, this feels like a writers choice sort of thing.

A bombardier beetle devotes nearly its entire abdomen section to store everything it need to fire a single shot; so, even if your bees had artificial biochemical weapons of similar capabilities, size and ammo would be a huge limiting feature making them impractical as a "hand"-held weapon system.  But with an airship, you could carry a large supply of peroxidase and hydrogen peroxide allowing your airships to broad-side each other with salvos of hot caustic spray.

If your airship has enough of these, they could offer an effective screen against enemy bees trying to rush your airship.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the square-cube law make the bow put out much more acceleration? If I understand correctly, the force is determined by the strength and flexibility, which is based on cross-sectional area, whereas evidently mass is based on volume. And the length over which it accelerates is obviously dependent on length

Comment: This draw length issue could disappear if this "bow" would have some reenforcement, something like a cross bow construct, maybe it requires winding a spring. the arrow is scaled down as well: the mass required is tiny when the arrow is sharp enough and the target would be an enemy bee.

Comment: They should use beelistas.

Comment: @IchthysKing for your revision, I think you misunderstood what I was saying. Armor efficacy scales at a X²:X³ ratio, not a X:X³ because getting bigger increases your surface area at a square rate.

Comment: As for the bow thing,  better materials only gets you so far. If your bees have access to steel, fiberglass composites, and all the things used in modern bow making, they could maybe get you up to 10fps: but that is still WAY too slow to harm an insect.  The cross section determines how much potential energy there is, but the material properties of the bow determines how quickly that energy is converted.  Longer bows shoot faster because acceleration from elasticity is compounded over the length of the bow arm.

Comment: @Goodies Square-cube law is working against you here.  If you have an arrow at 1:100th scale, then yes, it is driving its energy into 10,000 times less surface area, but it has 1,000,000 times less mass meaning it still gets 100x less penetration power than a larger arrow moving the same speed. If you could get an arrow that small moving at actual arrow speeds, then yes, it could pernitrate an organism designed like a human at that scale, but bees have thick exoskeletons; so, you would need the arrow to be moving much faster than a human arrow to pierce a bee's exoskeleton at that scale.

Comment: @Nosajimiki bees work together, it takes 3-4 bees per bow. They have large eyes they can't protect. At war they always get shot in the eye, with poisonous little pointy arrows. I'm sure, a bee veteran told me last week.

Answer (score 1):

### The square-cube law makes dirigibles less buoyant

Surface area : volume is higher than for a human aircraft. As with balloons, it's probably still feasible but hot air is unlikely to be at all practical; you will need lifting gas.

More importantly, the ability to carry food or cargo will be limited; the logistical situation will be more akin to a human plane than a huge dirigible.

The mass of the bees themselves and how many are out flying may matter too and be a parameter that needs to bee actively managed by your hive's president/politburo/prime minister (or even queen).

Comment: And be glad I do that. Imagine if on top of everything you guys have to deal with, you also had bees in dirigibles.